# How do I use the Selenium IDE plugin with Debian Linux?

Tags: selenium, debian

I'm trying to install the firefox plugin 'Selenium IDE' (from here: http://seleniumhq.org/download/ )

The problem is, that it's incompatible with debian's iceweasel.

How can I either install it with iceweasel, or get firefox to work on debian 64bit ?
(I know there's a nightly build of firefox 64bit, but that requires all kind of 32bit
libraries which I don't really want to install on that system)

regards

Answer (score 1):

first you remove previous browser

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
```

Then, download the latest Linux build of Firefox. Extract the files, and navigate to that folder, and run it. If you want, make an icon on your desktop. You can also make a link to the binary in **/usr/bin/firefox** to make it easier to launch.

get the package in your  /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
```

then run

```
apt-get update

  apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the link below

http://fisheye.olat.org/browse/~raw,r=1.2/OLAT/olat3/doc/test_doc/seleniumide_firefox.html firefox plugin 'Selenium IDE'

Comment: if I interpret that correctly then this is a way to install selenium for firefox, but debian doesn't have firefox, it has iceweasel, and the installation doesn't work with that